# Get background-image url using xpath

Tags: html, css, xpath

I'm trying to retrieve an url form background-image. So far i've managed to get the style however i can't seem to only get url.

What i managed so far:

```
//div[@class='opponent opponent1']/div[@class='team-player']/@style
```

Html example:

```
<div class="opponent opponent1">
    <div class="team-player" style="background-image: url('/uploads/test.jpeg')"></div>
    <h3><a href="#">Team EnVyUs</a></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of [`substring-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before) and [`substring-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after) should do the trick:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class='opponent opponent1']/div[@class='team-player']/@style, "background-image: url('"), "')")
```

Comment: Hi, can u help find why your solution dont work fo me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048955/extract-value-from-background-image-style-attribute-with-xpath ,  tks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are done with XPATH once you have selected the intended element. If you already got the style value you can use RegEX to get the url.

```
attribute.value.match(new RegEx("'(.*?)'"))[0];
```