# Extract value from background-image style attribute with xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Ii have the follow structure:

```
<div class="xGh" style="background-image: url('name_file.jpg');"></div>
```

I need that output:

`name_file.jpg`

I try use that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992013/get-background-image-url-using-xpath#answer-28992104), but dont work fo me :

```
$img = $xpath->query(substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class='xGh']/@style, "background-image: url('"), "')"));    

echo $img->item($i)->nodeValue."<br/>";
```

Look the error:

Test [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NoSAAE) with error

I have some error in that sintaxe i cant see how is correct...

<sub>sry my english</sub>

Comment: `substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class='xGh']/@style, "background-image: url('"), "')")` works well for me. What is the error message?

Comment: well : syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bd_all\sp\sp_c.php on line 22  >>> `echo $img->item($i)->nodeValue."<br/>" ;`

Comment: @Andersson can u help find that error or made 1 test with code that work fo r you? https://ideone.com/NoSAAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You lost quotes wrapping xpath - it's string.

2) with dom xpath, query returns set of nodes while to receive string result it's better to use `evaluate`

```
$img = $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class=\'xGh\']/@style, "background-image: url(\'"), "\')")');    

echo $img; // it contains name_file.jpg
```

[demo](https://eval.in/890778)

Comment: Related: [Selecting background url from style attribute with XPATH (and PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338327/2943403)